# Inserting a csv file into an Access database that is in a different location C#

Tags: c#, database, csv, ms-access, oledb

I am trying to insert data from a CSV file into a table in a local Access database but the CSV file is in a different location than my database. The insert statement is trying to insert a CSV file that is located in the Windows temporary folder but I keep getting an error saying that the object (CSV file) could not be found. Help would be appreciated, thank you!

Below is the error that I am receiving:

> The Microsoft Access database engine could not find the object 'S_M_85010747_201605.csv'. Make sure the object exists and that you spell its name and the path name correctly. If 'S_M_85010747_201605.csv' is not a local object, check your network connection or contact the server administrator.

Below is my code:

```
//CSV file name
string csvFile = ddlReportType.Text.Substring(0, 1) + "_"
                + ddlDateType.Text.Substring(0, 1) + "_" + lblVendorID.Text + "_" + txtDate.Text + ".csv";

        //Path for temporary folder
        string marFolder = Path.GetTempPath() + @"\MobileAppReports";

        //CSV file in temporary folder path
        string marCSVfolderPath = marFolder + @"\" + ddlReportType.Text.Substring(0, 1) + "_"
                + ddlDateType.Text.Substring(0, 1) + "_" + lblVendorID.Text + "_" + txtDate.Text + ".csv";


        var fileNameToInsert = Path.GetFileName(marCSVfolderPath);

        if (File.Exists(marCSVfolderPath))
        {
            OleDbCommand cmdBulk = new OleDbCommand(@"INSERT INTO SalesSummary" +
                            @"SELECT * FROM [Text;FMT=Delimited;HDR=Yes;ACCDB=Yes;Database=C:\Desktop].[" + fileNameToInsert + "]", MyConn);

            MyConn.Open();
            cmdBulk.ExecuteNonQuery();
            MyConn.Close();

            Directory.Delete(marFolder, true);//Deletes the csv file in the temp folder
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show(csvFile + " does not exist in the temp folder.");
        }
```

Comment: If you inspect `marCSVfolderPath`, does it show the correct location? Looks like you're using a folder name. Also, you should use string formats instead of concatenating that many strings.

Comment: It is the correct path. The string "marFolder" is the path to the temporary folder and it is concatenated to the string "marCSVfolderPath" because that is the name and location of the CSV file in the temp folder.

Comment: You say “CSV file in temporary folder path” but your SQL is trying to open it in `C:\Desktop`. Are those different paths? Show us what `marCSVfolderPath` contains.

Comment: Yeah, the Access database is located on the desktop and I am trying to insert a CSV file that is located in the temporary folder. marCSVfolderPath is in C:\users\username\AppData\Local\Temp\MobileAppMetrics\S_M_85010747_201605.csv

Comment: Your code is inserting a CSV file from `C:\Desktop`, not from `C:\users\username\AppData\Local\Temp\MobileAppMetrics`. Look at `cmdBulk` in the debugger.

Comment: @DourHighArch No I'm not. I'm specifying the database to insert the data into with Database=C:\Desktop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can see you define the csv file path and the temp file path, but i dont see where you copy the csv to the temp path so got no idea how it passes the File.Exists stage.

Also, your query string is only defining the fileNameToInsert and not the whole path. As others have stated, it also looks like your are defining the database path as the csv file.

Is this all of the code? Really feels like you missed something here.

Comment: Wow, you're right. Thank you all, I was able to figure it out with your help.